# Unable to install iPhone 5.x simulators on XCode 4.5

Tags: xcode

Trying to install the above and get the error message: "Failed with HTTP Status 499-Client error".  I'm using the pull-down menu "Install other simulators..."  (next to Schemes in XC).

This is what I'm getting after restarting the machine:
[image]

I'm dead in the water... can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried restarting Xcode or rebooting the computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wound up removing XC 4.4.1 and a previous version that was there... re-installed XC 4.5 and the simulators were able to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Sdk's/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk

Just copy and paste on other xcode where you need these simulator ni need to download again